# How do you save a user set layout against their database entry?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, controls

Okay so I'm working on a side project for one of my parents who's big into their gardening.

The idea is that they can log in to my app and layout the garden at home, creating controls for each part of the garden like a raised bed here, a polytunnel over there and so on.

What I'm struggling with is:

1. How to allow them to click on a given control, say a herb patch that they have added to the layout and positioned themselves, and then proceed to add in the information on the plants that are in that particular raised bed, i.e. Thyme, planted 12/12/12
2. To then allow them to save their layout and the information that they added to each control so that should they log back in to add a plant or tree that everything is where it was along with the information that they entered previously.

I have very little experience with this kind of thing and am aware that a database would be the first port of call but that is as the extent of my knowledge on the matter. I have searched far and wide for a solution but am yet to find anything that can help. Any ideas or even a point in the right direction would be great.